# ASUS M2N-SLI Deluxe problem

Tags: boot, motherboard

hi i'm having trouble with my computer so I thought I'd post and see if it isn't the former,I'll try to detail the symptoms as well as possible.

I've an asus m2n-sli deluxe motherboard with 2 ddr2 ram PC2-6400 1GB, after a year i've this computer today everytime i turn on the computer it starts up and shuts down after 4-5 seconds. I tried to clear cmos and it didn't work, i tested my ram on another computer and it booted perfectly then i tried to use another ram on my pc and it didn't work as always.
What i've tried so far is : removing connectors from dvd burner , hd and ram (and ofc it didn't work even if I disconnected 1 of them each  time). When the pc starts all the fan are working fine so i've really no idea of what could be the problem.Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck on this specific type of problem over on SuperUser. Additional info that might be relevant would be any overclocking you've carried out, what CPU you're using and what heatsink\fan and whether you built it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad PSU or motherboard. It can also be caused by not having the cooler secured on your CPU (in which case the CPU will overheat in a few seconds and trigger the thermal protection).